# Edit box with image background (borders) android

Tags: android, android-edittext, background-image

Can I customize edit box as shown below? I want edit box to be the image box so I can enter text in it.

[image]

Comment: you have to set this image as EditText Background and also make this image as 9-patch so it adjust EditText data.

Comment: Type "How to customize EditText in android" in Google, you will get your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this. http://www.techiecommunity.net/Android/Android-EditText-Background-Example

This has some examples of customize the EditText

You can also create the following image and add 9patch generator
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

and create the image and set background image of the EditText

> android:background="@drawable/image"

Comment: Thnx a lot. Really helpful !!